# Использование Scanner без импорта

Tags: импорт, scanner

даётся короткое задание , использовать класс Scanner без импорта, а конкретно вызвать метод nextLine и вывести текст "Test". Я не очень понял порядок ввода команды которая потребуется , идея ругается и выдаёт ошибки что нет ; там где она не должна стоять.
Пример моих неверных команд:

```java
java.util.Scanner scanner = scanner.nextLine();
java.util.Scanner.nextLine();
```

Прошу помощи и объяснения с порядком выставления команд.
Спасибо!

```java
class InputClass {
    public static String getString() {
      введите сюда код
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Использовать класс без импорта - значит объявлять его везде где возможно используя полное имя включающее пакет.

Соотв-но нужно:

1. Создать экземпляр класса (через `new`)
2. Воспользоваться методом экземпляра класса.

```java
class InputClass {
    public static String getString() {
      java.util.Scanner scanner = new java.util.Scanner("Test");
      return scanner.nextLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, теперь я понял!